# Grid "Tap" or "Click" event through a data template?

Tags: c#, command, windows-phone

I have already tried searching the web for using commands in Windows Phone, but I can't find a scenario that fits my problem. I have a `DataTemplate` which creates some grids. For these grids, I want them to do something when their `Click` event is triggered. However, **the `Grid` element doesn't have a `Command` property**.

I don't nescessarily need to do it through commands, but I thought that was the way to go.

Here's *what I want to do*.

```
<ItemsControl VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="RadioList">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="12" Tag="{Binding}">
                <!-- this is the grid I want to listen for clicks on -->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind a command to a grid you will need to use EventTrigger:

```
<ItemsControl VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="RadioList">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="12" Tag="{Binding}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommand}" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

with the following namespace definition:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```